# Output form submit success into page instead of redirect

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, wordpress

I'm using a WordPress sidebar widget for email capture for my newsletter. The plugin has been written to redirect to a 'success page' after submission, which isn't great because I'd rather it just output a success message in a div under the form after submission so the visitor stays on the page. How can I do that? I was thinking of something like a meta refresh on the success page back to the page the visitor was on, but that's pretty clunky when I'm pretty sure I've seen on-page email capture forms where the success message is just output into the page somewhere without a redirect.

If you don't mind, I'm going to copy quite a bit of the plugin's code here as I'm not exactly sure what needs to be tweaked here to get the kind of onsubmit I'm looking for. Or if there's any other way you could tell me to do this, I'd really appreciate your help with this. Thanks a lot.

```
<?php 
function wp_email_capture_form($error = 0) {
    $url = get_option('home');
    $url = addLastCharacter($url);
?>
<div id="wp_email_capture"><form name="wp_email_capture" method="post" action="<?php echo $url; ?>">
<?php
    if (isset($_GET["wp_email_capture_error"])) {
        $error = sanitize($_GET["wp_email_capture_error"]);
        echo "<div style='width:80%;background-color: #FFCCCC; margin: 5px;font-weight'>Error: ". $error ."</div>";
    }
?>
<label class="wp-email-capture-name">Name:</label> <input name="wp-email-capture-name" type="text" class="wp-email-capture-name"><br/>
<label class="wp-email-capture-email">Email:</label> <input name="wp-email-capture-email" type="text" class="wp-email-capture-email"><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="wp_capture_action" value="1">
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="wp-email-capture-submit">
</form>
</div>
<?php
    if (get_option("wp_email_capture_link") == 1) {
        echo "<p style='font-size:10px;'>Powered by <a      href='http://www.gospelrhys.co.uk/plugins/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-email-capture-plugin' target='_blank'>WP Email Capture</a></p>\n";
    }
}

function wp_email_capture_form_page($error = 0) {
    $url = get_option('home');
    $url = addLastCharacter($url);
    $display .= "<div id='wp_email_capture_2'><form name='wp_email_capture_display'     method='post' action='" . $url ."'>\n";
    if (isset($_GET["wp_email_capture_error"])) {
        $error = sanitize($_GET["wp_email_capture_error"]);
        $display .= "<div style='width:80%;background-color: #FFCCCC; margin:      5px;font-weight'>Error: ". $error ."</div>\n";
    } 
    $display .= "<label class='wp-email-capture-name'>Name:</label> <input name='wp-email-capture-name' type='text' class='wp-email-capture-name'><br/>\n";
    $display .= "<label class='wp-email-capture-email'>Email:</label> <input name='wp-email-capture-email' type='text' class='wp-email-capture-email'><br/>\n";
    $display .= "<input type='hidden' name='wp_capture_action' value='1'>\n";
    $display .= "<input name='Submit' type='submit' value='Submit' class='wp-email-capture-submit'></form></div>\n";
    if (get_option("wp_email_capture_link") == 1) {
        $display .= "<p style='font-size:10px;'>Powered by <a href='http://www.gospelrhys.co.uk/plugins/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-email-capture-plugin' target='_blank'>WP Email Capture</a></p>\n";
    } 

    return $display;
}

function wp_email_capture_display_form_in_post($content) {
    $get_form = wp_email_capture_form_page();
    $content = str_replace("[wp_email_capture_form]", $get_form, $content);
    return $content;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my first attempt at a Stack Overflow answer:

Your form action currently directs to a different page, but you need it to lead back to the page you're already on. You can do this with a blank action attribute, like so:

```
<form action="">
```

Once you've done this, you can use the `$_POST` data on that same page. In the page `div` where you want the output, try something like this:

```
if($_POST['wp_capture_action'] == 1)
{
    // The form has been submitted, so
    // print the success/failure message here
}
else
{
    // The form hasn't been submitted, so print
    // the form here.
}
```

I hope this helps!